# How to add a new node to cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

I am facing some problem while trying to add a new node to an existing cassandra cluster. I had two existing node, which are working in sync [Let's call them NodeA and NodeB]. Both of these are seed nodes.

Now I added a new node - NodeC. I was not automatically attached to the cluster for some reason. So, I stopped NodeA and NodeB and NodeC. And Started NodeA and NodeB first (as these are seed nodes) and then NodeC.

Now for some reason, I an getting this weird configuration under nodetool status:

On NodeA, I am getting -

```
Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack

UN  52.35.nodeB.IP  54.44 MB   256          ?       fc6d1bee-4b5e-4c18-bc7f-72195063dc44  rack1
```

and On NodeB and NodeC, I am getting -

```
Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack

UN  52.35.nodeB.IP  54.44 MB   256          ?       fc6d1bee-4b5e-4c18-bc7f-72195063dc44  rack1    
UN  52.11.nodeC.IP  35.96 MB   256          ?       7f76e652-0359-48a3-a3fd-13e1c3040c9b  rack1
```

Now, I don't understand why nodetool is giving different status on all three nodes.

Also, in this configuration, NodeA is is connected to NodeB only and NodeB and NodeC are connected to each other. I don't understand how this is possible.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: can you send the whole message you get with nodetool status?

Comment: what I think is that because you have two seeds, C connects to only one of them creating another database in your cluster. but I don't have enough information to infirm or confirm it

Answer (score 1):

Node C cannot connect to A and B. So it either is not aware of it, or cannot communicate.

Make sure your listen_address is set correctly in the cassandra.yaml on node C, and make sure that you have added node A and B in seeds in the cassandra.yaml also.